# Azure Redis Cache Service Timeout Issue

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache, azure-load-balancer

I am running the application in load balancer and using shared Azure Redis Cache service with connection pool of 50, but I am getting following timeout exception very frequently, Anyone please guide me what to do:

```
RedisTimeoutException
Timeout performing EXISTS (60000ms), next: GET vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/b81283a0-baf4-46df-a616-fbdd9d387034##CheckOutFiles, inst: 6, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: Inactive, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, serverEndpoint: mr4devops.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: inteGREAT.Web.UI.v2_IN_1(SE.Redis-v2.6.66.47313), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=151,Free=32616,Min=4,Max=32767), v: 2.6.66.47313 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)   
at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server, T defaultValue) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1867   
at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.KeyExists(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisDatabase.cs:line 811
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are facing a time out error when running application in load balancer using shared Azure Redis Cache with connection pool of 50.

The answer is in that link included in the exception message. The number of busy worker threads is greater than the min, so you will need to increase the min.

Hope that helps